# what is the printf in C#

Tags: c#, printing, format, printf, console-output

I want to know what to use in C# to format my output in my console window
I tried to use \t but it did not work

I know there is printf in C to format my output

check this image
https://s15.postimg.cc/94fstpi2z/Console.png

Comment: `string.Format`, or directly the [relevant overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx) of `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 40):

There is no direct "printf" duplication in C#. You can use PInvoke to call it from a C library.

However there is

```
Console.WriteLine("args1: {0} args2: {1}", value1, value2);
```

Or

```
Console.Write("args1: {0} args2: {1}", value1, value2);
```

Or

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("args1: {0} args2: {1}", value1, value2));
```

Or

```
Console.Write(string.Format("args1: {0} args2: {1}", value1, value2));
```

Or (C#6+ only)

```
Console.WriteLine($"args1: {value1} args2: {value2}");
```

Or (C#6+ only)

```
Console.Write($"args1: {value1} args2: {value2}");
```

Comment: Note that the first two call `String.Format`. There is no functional difference between your two versions.

Comment: I know, it was just for demonstration, because sometimes you'd like to format the string and maybe do some other manipulation to it before writing to the standard output stream.

Comment: Maybe, for the sake of completness, add an example with interpolated strings (just mention its available in C#6 and not before)

Comment: Added interpolated strings example now :)